# how to call a column name using loop:

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm very new to R, and I would like to know what is the best way to call a different column using for loop.

My code goes like this:

```
Variables <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","Var6","Var7")
Years <- c(2015,2016,2017,2018)

for (Year in Years) {
    for (Var in Variables) {
        TT = auc(data[data$Def_Year==Year,]$Good_Bad,
                 data[data$Def_Year==Year,]$Var)
        print (TT)
    }
}
```

I'm tryng to calculate the AUC (area under roc curve) for each variable in each year in order to check the credit scoring model performance stability.
The thing is R does not understand the `$Var` command. In excel I sometimes use `&` to overcome such obstacles. I would love to hear your recommendations.

Comment: maybe you have to use this `data[data$Def_Year==Year,"Good_Bad"],data[data$Def_Year==Year,"Var"]`

Answer (score 2):

Hi you could do something like this. See my sample code below

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(4,5,6))
variables <- c("v1", "v2")

for(var in variables) {
   print(df[, var])
}
Output:
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 4 5 6
```

I have not solved your code directly as it is not advised on SO to solve the task fully but rather to give general guideline towards solution. I would suggest you go through this: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/subsetting-data/ to better understand subsetting in R.
Also see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing to understand the indexing in R.
From above:

> The form using $ applies to recursive objects such as lists and pairlists. It allows only a literal character string or a symbol as the index. That is, the index is **not computable**: for cases where you need to evaluate an expression to find the index, use x[[expr]]. Applying $ to a non-recursive object is an error.